# how to Call a function from wordpress plugin settings page on a button click of wordpress plugin

Tags: php, function, wordpress

I m new to a make a plugin..Basically i want to have one update button in my plugin option page which will call few function from my plugin page ..

My option page looks like this

```
<div class="wrap">

    <?php screen_icon(); ?>
    <form action="options.php" method="post" id="<?php echo $plugin_id; ?>_options_form" name="<?php echo $plugin_id; ?>_options_form">

    <?php settings_fields($plugin_id.'_options'); ?>

    <h2>Plugin Options &raquo; Settings</h2>
    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
           <tr>
             <th><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Settings" class="button-primary" style="padding:8px;" /></th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
           <tr>
    </table>

    </form>

</div>
```

My plugin page contains few functions as follows

```
function get_images(){

    global $post; 
    global $wpdb;
    $query_images_args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment' , 'post_mime_type' =>'image','post_status' => 'published', 'posts_per_page' => -1,'numberposts' => 1
 );


 $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
 $images = array();

         $abc=($images);
                 $count = count($images);
                 for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
 {

      $final[]= $images[$i];

 }

                 if(count($abc)>1){
                 $_SESSION['arrayImg']=$abc;  
                 }
                  $noofpics=  count($image);
    }
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'get_images');
```

and another two functions in my plugin page. So on click of update button i want to call this few functions ..Plz help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem actually by using

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0), myFunction();" VALUE="Update">
```

The php code when it runs does executes the line of code and hence when the user is on this page the function can be executed on button click of `update` button..

My problem is solved by this ...